# Docker: How to get many instance of the same docker image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker , and I'm wondering how to get two or three instance of the same docker image.
Following this structure.

Each instance have a unique port and configuration.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Multiple instances of an image? Are you asking how to create multiple containers from the same image? Or do you want multiple tags for the same image?

Comment: it's to have multiple images at the same container that each one have a unique port and configuration.

Comment: "multiple images at the same container" does not parse. A container only has a single image. The image is the definition needed to create a container, which is a running instance of an image.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your response. but we can have many running containers of the same image?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
version: '3'
    services:
      container1:
        image: WEB-APP
        ports:
          - 8082:80
      container2:
        image: WEB-APP
        ports:
          - 8083:80
      container3:
        image: WEB-APP
        ports:
          - 8084:80
```

Put it into a file called 'docker-compose.yml' somewhere on your machine and run:

```
docker-compose up
```

in the folder of the file, after installing Compose (https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).

If you plan to use multiple containers of the same image look into https://kubernetes.io/.

Comment: yes, my objective at the end is to create images on kubernets https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-stateless-application-deployment/